# How can I normalize line endings of XML documents and XSLT templates using SVN?

Tags: xml, svn, normalization, eol

I need to make sure XML and XSLT files are checked in with consistent line endings regardless of the IDE or operating system used for development. How do I configure SVN to do this, and get the rest of my team to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the config file for your svn client:

```
vi ~/.subversion/config
```

Add or uncomment the following settings:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
*.xml = svn:eol-style=native
*.xsd = svn:eol-style=native
*.xsl = svn:eol-style=native
```

Document this on the team wiki.

Create an alias to convert existing files, and share it with the team:

```
alias svn_clean='svn propset svn:eol-style "native" *; svn commit'
```

**References**

- [Apache Subversion FAQ: auto-props](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#auto-props)
- [Subversion Client Configuration](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDEV/subversion-client-configuration.html)